# shop that has served more than 3 people query sql

Tags: sql

I have a table called `frequents` that has two columns `name` and `pizzeria`. Each name is linked to a pizzeria. Some names are mentioned more than once since they are linked to different pizzerias. I need help writing a query that shows all the pizzerias that have served more than 3 people. Thank you.

```
Name Pizzareia
Amy Pizza Hut
Ben Pizza Hut
Ben Chicago Pizza
Cal Straw Hat
Cal New York Pizza
Dan Straw Hat
Dan New York Pizza
Eli Straw Hat
Eli Chicago Pizza
Fay Dominos
Fay Little Caesars
Gus Chicago Pizza
Gus Pizza Hut
Hil Dominos
Hil Straw Hat
Hil Pizza Hut
Ian New York Pizza
Ian Straw Hat
Ian Dominos
```

And the query:

```
SELECT name, count(pizzeria)
FROM frequency
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(pizzeria) >= 3
```

The result is supposed to show the pizzeria where its name has come up more than 3 times

Comment: Is this query giving you the wrong result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need help writing a query that shows all the pizzerias that have served more than 3 people

You need to `GROUP BY pizzeria`, not by `name`:

```
SELECT pizzeria FROM frequency GROUP BY pizzeria HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot but it is not quite what I am looking for the output should only have the name of the restaurants that has been mentioned more than 3 times

Comment: @TrueNaijaKing: ok, so you just need to remove the count from the result. I updated my query.